# Flash Player Hardware decoding use or not?

Tags: hardware, flash, decoding

When I use Flash Player hardware decoing, I found brwoser crash problem like below link.
it can be solved by disabling hardware video decoding
(netStream.useHardwareDecoder = false)
But I would like to know the performance difference, when i use Flash hardware decoder or not. (Playing delay...etc)

https://forums.adobe.com/message/7172850?tstart=0#7172850

Comment: Like that shown link, are you using video with transparency effect (alpha channel)? Anyway I cant say about performance but to avoid crashes you could try to adjust the **WMODE** in the html page of SWF. You can read up on options at **[this PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)** (scroll to near bottom). You can also check **[this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698960/2057709)** for hints

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I check the link.